# Умное слияние двух таблиц в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, обработка-данных

Подскажите как объединить 2 таблицы, что бы при этом не потерять кол-во строк. Пример:

Табл.А

```
-  1  2  3
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

Табл.Б

```
-  2  4
0  3  1
1  4  2
```

Пробовал merge, outer:

```
-   1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  4.0  1.0
2  NaN  4.0  NaN  2.0
```

При этом при слиянии теряется одна строка.

А нужно так:

```
-   1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
1  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN
2  NaN  3.0  NaN  1.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN  2.0
```

Тоесть по тем признакам по которым нет значений в страке NaN.

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и приведите пример того, как должен выглядеть ответ

Comment: Правильное замечание, сейчас поробую. Уже пробовал. Вижу что он корявый. Пример внизу привел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [8]: C = pd.concat([A,B], ignore_index=True)

In [9]: C
Out[9]:
     1  2    3    4
0  1.0  2  3.0  NaN
1  2.0  3  4.0  NaN
2  NaN  3  NaN  1.0
3  NaN  4  NaN  2.0
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Супер, получилось. Спасибо.